# How do I use the ML sklearn pipeline to predict?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have created an ML pipeline using sklearn_pandas and sklearn. It looks like this.

```py
features = ['ColA','ColB','ColC']
labels = 'ColD'

mapper = sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper([
    ('ColB',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('ColC',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler())
])
pipe = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline([
        ('featurize', mapper),
        ('imputer', imputer),
        ('logreg', sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression())
])
cross_val_score = sklearn_pandas.cross_val_score(pipe,traindf[features],
                                                 traindf[labels],
                                                 'log_loss')
```

I like the model and the `'log_loss'` values that I am getting.
How do I use this pipeline to predict my test set?

When I do `pipe.predict(testX[features])` I get an error that says:

> 'StandardScaler' object has no attribute 'mean_'

I have checked my test set. It looks fine.

Comment: Try doing `pipe.fit(traindf[features], traindf[labels])` first.

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked. Realized my mistake. I guess even though pipe gives me the validation score, in order to predict, one will need to fit the data once again, in order to predict. One question i still have is that now what is the use case for the pipe.fit_transform method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fit the pipeline first, like you fit any model/transformer:

```
pipe.fit(traindf[features], traindf[labels])
```